# Redirect all contents of subfolder to matching urls in root directory

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I need to move my store which is currently in a subfolder (www.example.com/store) to the root directory and am trying to figure out how to correctly redirect everything.  My site contains thousands of pages and images all of which are currently in the /store folder and I don't want to lose my links and SEO standing when I move it to the root.  The new URLS will be identical except the /store part will no longer be necessary.  For example, www.example.com/store/image1.jpg will need to be redirected to www.example.com/image1.jpg - I need to do this for every page and every image that currently exists in /store.

Is there an easy way to automatically do this all at once, one piece of code that will automatically redirect everything that used to be in /store to it's matching page without /store?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this single rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file (a level above store):

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^store(/.*)?$ $1 [L,NC]
```